Quadratic covariation of martingale transforms to simple processes.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be simple processes, that is $X_t=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\xi_n{1}_{(t_{n},t_{n+1}]}(t)$ for a uniformly bounded sequence $(\xi_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of random variables so that $\xi_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t_n}$-measurable and $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots$ an increasing sequence of nonrandom times. Additionally, let $M$ and $N$ be two square integrable continuous martingales. It is assumed that all processes and random variables are measurable and adapted to the underlying filtrations so that one may use the tools required. Additionally note that $X$ is progressive and bounded as $(\xi_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is $(\mathcal{F}_{t_n})_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$-adapted.
I am trying to show, with $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the bilinear quadratic covariation and $X\cdot M$ the stochastic integral of $X$ with respect to $M$, that
$$
\langle X\cdot M,Y\cdot N\rangle=\int_0^\cdot XY\mathrm{d}\langle M,N\rangle.
$$
I figured, without loss of generality, that $X$ and $Y$ jump on the same grid, meaning that $Y_t=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\varphi_n{1}_{(t_{n},t_{n+1}]}(t)$ where the increasing sequence $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is identical to the one used in the construction of $X$. By the (bi)linearity of the quadratic covariation, we may write
\begin{align}
\langle X\cdot M,Y\cdot N\rangle_t&=\langle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\xi_n(M_{t_n\wedge t}-M_{t_{n-1}\wedge t}),\sum_{m=0}^\infty\varphi_m(N_{t_m\wedge t}-N_{t_{m-1}\wedge t})\rangle\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\xi_n\varphi_m\langle M_{t_n\wedge t}-M_{t_{n-1}\wedge t},N_{t_m\wedge t}-N_{t_{m-1}\wedge t}\rangle\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\xi_n\varphi_n\langle M_{t_n\wedge t}-M_{t_{n-1}\wedge t},N_{t_n\wedge t}-N_{t_{n-1}\wedge t}\rangle.
\end{align}
Yet from here, I seem to be rather stuck. Given that for any simple process $X$ and square integrable continuous martingale $M$, we know that $\langle X\cdot M\rangle=\int_0^\cdot X_u^2\mathrm{d}\langle M\rangle_u$, hence I believe that the next step involves using the polarisation formula $\langle x,y\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(\langle x+y\rangle-\langle x-y\rangle)$, yet I do not see the final step(s) yet.
The question comes from equation 6.9 on page 42 in the lecture notes Stochastic Integration.
Any help is welcome!

Hint: Proposition 4.10

Consider stopping times $T>S$ and stopping times $T'>S'$. Moreover, $\xi_T$ shall be the coefficient for $(S,T]$ and $\varphi_{T'}$ the coefficient for $(S',T']$.
Using Proposition 4.10, you find Lemma 6.10 for simple functions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle\xi_T(M^T-M^S),N\rangle_t
&=\xi_T(\langle M^T,N\rangle_t-\langle M^S,N\rangle_t)\\
&=\xi_T(\langle M,N\rangle^T_t-\langle M,N\rangle^S_t)\\
&=\xi_T(\langle M,N\rangle_{T\wedge t}-\langle M,N\rangle_{S\wedge t})
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, you apply this twice and get Lemma 6.11 for simple functions:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\langle\xi_T(M^T-M^S),\varphi_{T'}(N^{T'}-N^{S'})\rangle_t\\
&=\xi_T(\langle M,\varphi_{T'}(N^{T'}-N^{S'})\rangle_{T\wedge t}-\langle M,\varphi_{T'}(N^{T'}-N^{S'})\rangle_{S\wedge t})\\
&=\xi_T\varphi_{T'}(\langle M,N\rangle_{T'\wedge(T\wedge t)}-\langle M,N\rangle_{S'\wedge(T\wedge t)})\\
&\quad -\xi_T\varphi_{T'} ( \langle M,N\rangle_{T'\wedge(S\wedge t)}-\langle M,N\rangle_{S'\wedge(S\wedge t)})
\end{aligned}
$$
For example, if $T'\ge T>S\ge S'$, it holds
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle\xi_T(M^T-M^S),\varphi_{T'}(N^{T'}-N^{S'})\rangle_t
&=\xi_T\varphi_{T'} ( \langle M,N\rangle_{T\wedge t}-\langle M,N\rangle_{S\wedge t})
\end{aligned}
$$
All the other cases behave as desired. Especially the cases $T'>S'\ge T>S$ and $T>S\ge T'>S'$ are equal to $0$.

In your notation, you would choose $T=t_n$, $S=t_{n-1}$, $T'=t_m$, $S'=t_{m-1}$, as well as the coefficients $\xi_T=\xi_n$ and $\varphi_{T'}=\varphi_m$, which reads as
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\langle\xi_n(M^{t_n}-M^{t_{n-1}}),\varphi_m(N^{t_m}-N^{t_{m-1}})\rangle_t\\
&=\xi_n\varphi_{m}(\langle M,N\rangle_{t_m\wedge(t_n\wedge t)}-\langle M,N\rangle_{t_{m-1}\wedge(t_n\wedge t)})\\
&\quad -\xi_n\varphi_{m} ( \langle M,N\rangle_{t_{m}\wedge(t_{n-1}\wedge t)}-\langle M,N\rangle_{t_{m-1}\wedge(t_{n-1}\wedge t)})
\end{aligned}
$$
As you have stated, you can also choose the same grid without loss of generality. Then,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\langle\xi_n(M^{t_n}-M^{t_{n-1}}),\varphi_n(N^{t_n}-N^{t_{n-1}})\rangle_t\\
&=\xi_n\varphi_{n}(\langle M,N\rangle_{t_n\wedge(t_n\wedge t)}-\langle M,N\rangle_{t_{n-1}\wedge(t_n\wedge t)})\\
&\quad -\xi_n\varphi_{n} ( \langle M,N\rangle_{t_{n}\wedge(t_{n-1}\wedge t)}-\langle M,N\rangle_{t_{n-1}\wedge(t_{n-1}\wedge t)})\\
&=\xi_n\varphi_{n}(\langle M,N\rangle_{t_n\wedge t}-\langle M,N\rangle_{t_{n-1}\wedge t})\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and for $n\ne m$, you find
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\langle\xi_n(M^{t_n}-M^{t_{n-1}}),\varphi_m(N^{t_m}-N^{t_{m-1}})\rangle_t\\
&=\xi_n\varphi_{m}(\langle M,N\rangle_{t_m\wedge(t_n\wedge t)}-\langle M,N\rangle_{t_{m-1}\wedge(t_n\wedge t)})\\
&\quad -\xi_n\varphi_{m} ( \langle M,N\rangle_{t_{m}\wedge(t_{n-1}\wedge t)}-\langle M,N\rangle_{t_{m-1}\wedge(t_{n-1}\wedge t)})\\
&=0
\end{aligned}
$$
such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle X\cdot M, Y\cdot N\rangle_t
&=\langle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\xi_n(M^{t_n}-M^{t_{n-1}}),\sum_{m=0}^\infty\varphi_m(N^{t_m}-N^{t_{m-1}})\rangle_t\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\langle\xi_n(M^{t_n}-M^{t_{n-1}}),\varphi_m(N^{t_m}-N^{t_{m-1}})\rangle_t\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\Big[\xi_n\varphi_{m}(\langle M,N\rangle_{t_m\wedge(t_n\wedge t)}-\langle M,N\rangle_{t_{m-1}\wedge(t_n\wedge t)})\\
&\quad\quad\quad -\xi_n\varphi_{m} ( \langle M,N\rangle_{t_{m}\wedge(t_{n-1}\wedge t)}-\langle M,N\rangle_{t_{m-1}\wedge(t_{n-1}\wedge t)})\Big]\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\xi_n\varphi_{n}(\langle M,N\rangle_{t_n\wedge t}-\langle M,N\rangle_{t_{n-1}\wedge t})\\
&=\int_0^t (XY)_s d\langle M,N\rangle_s
\end{aligned}
$$

A very nice proof! Many thanks for the time and help!

You're welcome! If something isn't satisfactory yet, feel free to reach out. Otherwise, please consider accepting the answer, such that the topic can be closed.
